# Swift's way to handle this situation instead of using bools

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, boolean

I have a function that I want only to execute if not executing currently.
I have used a bool variable to check the current execution.

Is there any other solution provided by Swift to handle this instead of using Bool?

```
 guard
        !isExecuting,
        let currentNavVC = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
        else { return }
    
    isExecuting = true
    
    let first = currentNavVC.viewControllers.first,
    let last = currentNavVC.viewControllers.last
    var controllers = [first]
    if first != last {
        controllers = [first, last]
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        currentNavVC.viewControllers = controllers
        isExecuting = false
    }
```

Bool variable: **isExecuting**

#### Note:

Tried using Semaphores(*DispatchSemaphore*) but they are of no help.
Also I am calling the above function in didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
**Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance!!**

Comment: There should be no problem with this code unless you are going to use `isExecuting` right after the `DispatchQueue` closure and expect it's `false`

Comment: The code is executing all right, but I want to know if it is possible without using bool. @vadian

Comment: Why? It's a pretty reasonable way.

Comment: You could check for view controllers' count. Something like `currentNavVC.viewControllers.count != 2`

Comment: currentNavVC.viewControllers.count != 2 will not help as the function is called multiple times. I have called the function from didReceiveMemoryWarning() @Desdenova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you also can use `Operation` with `OperationQueue` in this case.

`Operation` supports cancellation as well as checking if it is executing.

Ref:

OperationQueue: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue

Operation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation

Comment: Thanks! Operation queues will work but what I want is all other calls to this method gets rejected, if it is already executing. When using operation queues, the method calls are saved and executed on current operation completion. I don't want to save extra method calls for later execution.

Comment: I think it would work if you keep an `Operation` as an optional variable like `var currentOperation: Operation?`, later you can just call `currentOperation?.cancel()` then create another `Operation` for `currentOperation` and execute it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am using an optional BlockOperation and on completion setting it to nil. Also maxConcurrentOperationCount is set to 1 for OperationQueue as to allow only single operation execution. Thanks for the help

Comment: Great! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a function that I want only to execute if not executing currently

You're looking for a *lock*. But locks of themselves are tricky and dangerous. The easy, safe way to get a lock is to use a serial queue. As we say, a serial queue is a form of lock. So:

- If your function is called on the main queue, then it *cannot* execute if it is executing currently, and there is nothing to do. The main queue is a serial queue and there can be Only One.
- If your function is called on a background queue, then make sure that your queue is a serial queue. For example, if you create your own DispatchQueue, it is serial by default.